# Seg fault when using structure pointers to access struct members in C

Tags: c, pointers, structure

What is wrong with my program, I get seg fault when I try to print the values.

My aim is assign some values in sample_function.

and in main function I want to copy the structure to another structure.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char        *name;
    char        *class;
    char        *rollno;
} test;

test *
sample_function ()
{
    test *abc;
    abc = (test *)malloc(sizeof(test));

    strcpy(abc->name,"Microsoft");
    abc->class = "MD5";
    abc->rollno = "12345";
printf("%s %s %s\n",abc->name,abc->class,abc->rollno);
return abc;

}

int main(){

test   *digest_abc = NULL;
   test   *abc = NULL;

abc = sample_function();

digest_abc = abc;
printf(" %s  %s  %s \n",digest_abc->name,digest_abc->class,digest_abc->rollno);

return 1;

}
```

Pointer has always been a nightmare for me, I never understood it.

Comment: You haven't allocated memory for `abc` => undefined behaviour.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: Why you are only using strcpy for name but not class and rollno?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
test * sample_function ()
{
    test *abc;

    strcpy(abc->name,"Surya");
```

What do you think `abc` points to, here? The answer is, it doesn't really point to anything. You need to initialize it to something, which in this case means allocating some memory.

So, let's fix that first issue:

```
test * sample_function ()
{
    test *abc = malloc(sizeof(*abc));

    strcpy(abc->name,"Surya");
```

Now, `abc` points to something, and we can store stuff in there!

But ... `abc->name` is a pointer too, and what do you think *that* points to? Again, it doesn't really point to anything, and you certainly can't assume it points somewhere you can store your string.

So, let's fix your second issue:

```
test * sample_function ()
{
    test *abc = malloc(sizeof(*abc));

    abc->name = strdup("Surya");
    /* ... the rest is ok ... */
    return abc;
}
```

Now, there's one last issue: you never *release* the memory you just allocated (this probably isn't an issue here, but it'd be a bug in a full-sized program).

So, at the end of main, you should have something like

```
    free(abc->name);
    free(abc);
    return 1;
}
```

---

The final issue is a design one: you have three pointers in your structure, and only convention to help you remember which is dynamically allocated (and must be freed) and which point to string literals (and *must not* be freed).

That's fine, so long as this convention is followed *everywhere*. As soon as you dynamically allocate `class` or `rollno`, you have a memory leak. As soon as you point `name` at a string literal, you'll have a crash and/or heap damage.

As *japreiss* points out in a comment, a good way to *enforce* your convention is to write dedicated functions, like:

```
void initialize_test(test *obj, const char *name, char *class, char *rollno) {
    obj->name = strdup(name);
    ...
}
void destroy_test(test *obj) {
    free(obj->name);
}
test *malloc_test(const char *name, ...) {
    test *obj = malloc(sizeof(*obj));
    initialize_test(obj, name, ...);
    return test;
}
void free_test(test *obj) {
    destroy_test(obj);
    free(obj);
}
```

Comment: I have tried allocating memory by malloc, still hitting seg fault - code edited

Comment: congratulations, you hit the second bug while I was editing it into my answer :)

Comment: That solved it thanks, one last question if I free memory allocated to abc and still want to store values in digest_abc - how do I do that

Comment: +1 this kind of nested memory allocation for structs is common, and it's a good idea to wrap it in a "constructor" function like `void initialize_test(test *the_test, char *name, char *class, char *rollno)` that takes care of all the allocation and copying, and `void cleanup_test(test *obj)` to free memory.

Answer (score 1):

In your function `sample_function` you return a pointer to `abc`. You *cannot* do this in C due to the way *[Activation Records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)* are organized.

An Activation Record is a data structure that contains all the relevant information for a function call, parameters, return address, addresses of local variables, etc...

When you call a function a new Activation Record gets *pushed* onto the stack it could look something like this.

```
// Record for some function f(a, b)
| local variable 1  | <- stack pointer  (abc in your case)
| local variable 2  |
| old stack pointer | <- base pointer
| return address    |   
| parameter 1       |
| parameter 2       |
---------------------
| caller activation | 
|   record          |
```

When you return from a function this same activation record gets *popped* off of the stack but what happens if you returned the address of a variable that was on the old record ?

```
// popped record
| local variable 1  | <- address of abc   #
| local variable 2  |                     #
| old stack pointer |                     # Unallocated memory, any new function
| return address    |                     # call could overwrite this
| parameter 1       |                     #
| parameter 2       |                     # 
--------------------- <- stack pointer 
| caller activation | 
|   record          |
```

Now you try to use abc and your program *correctly* crashes because it sees that you are accessing an area of memory that is unallocated.

You also have problems with allocation, but other answers have already covered that.

Comment: The pointer `test *abc` is returned by value. The address of `abc`, which would be a `test **` and would indeed be out of scope, doesn't appear anywhere I can see.

Comment: @Useless I thought it was pretty common terminology, but yes stack frame could be used also.

Comment: I looked it up and edited that comment out before your response - it was just unfamiliar :)

Comment: Um, I still think the _address of abc_ thing is a red herring though - the address of abc is never taken.

Comment: @Useless Isn't that what is being returned ? I just re-read what I wrote, I meant to say address of the *pointer* to `abc`; not `abc` itself

Comment: I see `return abc`, not `return &abc`. That means the pointer is returned by value which (once initialized properly) is fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31772/discussion-between-useless-and-hunter-mcmillen)

Answer (score 0):

In `sample_function` you declare `abc` as a pointer to a `test` structure, but you never initialize it.  It's just pointing off into the weeds somewhere.  Then you try to dereference it to store values - BOOM.

Your program doesn't need any pointers at all; structures can be passed by value in C.

If you do want to keep similar interfaces to what you have now, you're going to have to add some dynamic allocations (`malloc`/`free` calls) to make sure your structures are actually allocated and that your pointers actually point to them.

Comment: He's also not allocating any memory for the strings.

Comment: Yup, it's true.  That only matters for one of them, though.